# Speed-improvement on large pandas read_csv with datetime index

Tags: python, performance, pandas, date-formatting

I have enormous files that look like this:

05/31/2012,15:30:00.029,1306.25,1,E,0,,1306.25

05/31/2012,15:30:00.029,1306.25,8,E,0,,1306.25

I can easily read them using the following:

```
  pd.read_csv(gzip.open("myfile.gz"), header=None,names=
  ["date","time","price","size","type","zero","empty","last"], parse_dates=[[0,1]])
```

Is there any way to efficiently parse dates like this into pandas timestamps?  If not, is there any guide for writing a cython function that can passed to date_parser= ?

I tried writing my own parser function and it still takes too long for the project I am working on.

Comment: So the read_csv function meets your parsing needs but is too slow?

Comment: Yes, essentially.  If there is no easy solution, I wanted to see if someone could give guideline for handling this in cython.

Comment: It confuses me that `pd.Timestamp` doesn't work (it does individually e.g. with `pd.Timestamp('05/31/2012,15:30:00.029')`). The fact it doesn't is most likely a bug.

Comment: posted as [an issue on github](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/2932).

Comment: Fixed the bug in git master

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An improvement of previous [solution of Michael WS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15812787/2447082):

- conversion to `pandas.Timestamp` is better to perform outside the Cython code
- `atoi` and processing native-c strings is a little-bit faster than python funcs
- the number of `datetime`-lib calls is reduced to one from 2 (+1 occasional for date)
- microseconds are also processed

NB! The date order in this code is day/month/year.

All in all the code seems to be approximately 10 times faster than the original `convert_date_cython`. However if this is called after `read_csv` then on SSD hard drive the difference is total time is only few percents due to the reading overhead. I would guess that on regular HDD the difference would be even smaller.

```
cimport numpy as np
import datetime
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from libc.stdlib cimport atoi, malloc, free 
from libc.string cimport strcpy

### Modified code from Michael WS:
### https://stackoverflow.com/a/15812787/2447082

def convert_date_fast(np.ndarray date_vec, np.ndarray time_vec):
    cdef int i, d_year, d_month, d_day, t_hour, t_min, t_sec, t_ms
    cdef int N = len(date_vec)
    cdef np.ndarray out_ar = np.empty(N, dtype=np.object)  
    cdef bytes prev_date = <bytes> 'xx/xx/xxxx'
    cdef char *date_str = <char *> malloc(20)
    cdef char *time_str = <char *> malloc(20)

    for i in range(N):
        if date_vec[i] != prev_date:
            prev_date = date_vec[i] 
            strcpy(date_str, prev_date) ### xx/xx/xxxx
            date_str[2] = 0 
            date_str[5] = 0 
            d_year = atoi(date_str+6)
            d_month = atoi(date_str+3)
            d_day = atoi(date_str)

        strcpy(time_str, time_vec[i])   ### xx:xx:xx:xxxxxx
        time_str[2] = 0
        time_str[5] = 0
        time_str[8] = 0
        t_hour = atoi(time_str)
        t_min = atoi(time_str+3)
        t_sec = atoi(time_str+6)
        t_ms = atoi(time_str+9)

        out_ar[i] = datetime.datetime(d_year, d_month, d_day, t_hour, t_min, t_sec, t_ms)
    free(date_str)
    free(time_str)
    return pd.to_datetime(out_ar)
```

Answer (score 7):

I got an incredible speedup (50X) with the following cython code:

call from python:
timestamps = convert_date_cython(df["date"].values, df["time"].values)

```
cimport numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import numpy as np
def convert_date_cython(np.ndarray date_vec, np.ndarray time_vec):
    cdef int i
    cdef int N = len(date_vec)
    cdef out_ar = np.empty(N, dtype=np.object)
    date = None
    for i in range(N):
        if date is None or date_vec[i] != date_vec[i - 1]:
            dt_ar = map(int, date_vec[i].split("/"))
            date = datetime.date(dt_ar[2], dt_ar[0], dt_ar[1])
        time_ar = map(int, time_vec[i].split(".")[0].split(":"))
        time = datetime.time(time_ar[0], time_ar[1], time_ar[2])
        out_ar[i] = pd.Timestamp(datetime.datetime.combine(date, time))
    return out_ar
```

Answer (score 2):

The cardinality of datetime strings is not huge. For example, number of time strings in the format `%H-%M-%S` is `24 * 60 * 60 = 86400`. If the number of rows of your dataset is much larger than this or your data contains lots of duplicate timestamps, adding a cache in the parsing process could substantially speed things up.

For those who do not have Cython available, here's an alternative solution in pure python:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime


def parse_datetime(dt_array, cache=None):
    if cache is None:
        cache = {}
    date_time = np.empty(dt_array.shape[0], dtype=object)
    for i, (d_str, t_str) in enumerate(dt_array):
        try:
            year, month, day = cache[d_str]
        except KeyError:
            year, month, day = [int(item) for item in d_str[:10].split('-')]
            cache[d_str] = year, month, day
        try:
            hour, minute, sec = cache[t_str]
        except KeyError:
            hour, minute, sec = [int(item) for item in t_str.split(':')]
            cache[t_str] = hour, minute, sec
        date_time[i] = datetime(year, month, day, hour, minute, sec)
    return pd.to_datetime(date_time)


def read_csv(filename, cache=None):
    df = pd.read_csv(filename)
    df['date_time'] = parse_datetime(df.loc[:, ['date', 'time']].values, cache=cache)
    return df.set_index('date_time')
```

With the following particular data set, the speedup is 150x+:

```
$ ls -lh test.csv
-rw-r--r--  1 blurrcat  blurrcat   1.2M Apr  8 12:06 test.csv
$ head -n 4 data/test.csv
user_id,provider,date,time,steps
5480312b6684e015fc2b12bc,fitbit,2014-11-02 00:00:00,17:47:00,25
5480312b6684e015fc2b12bc,fitbit,2014-11-02 00:00:00,17:09:00,4
5480312b6684e015fc2b12bc,fitbit,2014-11-02 00:00:00,19:10:00,67
```

In ipython:

```
In [1]: %timeit pd.read_csv('test.csv', parse_dates=[['date', 'time']])
1 loops, best of 3: 10.3 s per loop
In [2]: %timeit read_csv('test.csv', cache={})
1 loops, best of 3: 62.6 ms per loop
```

To limit memory usage, simply replace the dict cache with something like a LRU.

Comment: In my example, its millisecond stamped.   It's enormous
15:30:00.029

Comment: @MichaelWS so you may use 1k additional items in cache, you get the point