# python pandas read_csv how to speed up processing timestamps

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp

(pandas 0.16.1, Python 2.7.8 Anaconda 2.1.0 (64-bit), Intel Xeon 3.07GHz, Win7 64bit)

I have a csv table of quote data. About 400k rows per day.

```
sym         time                    bid     ask     bsize asize
XCME@6EM4   2014.05.07T08:10:02.407 1.3927  1.3928  28    29
XCME@6EM4   2014.05.07T08:10:02.430 1.3927  1.3928  27    29
```

To read this into Python with pandas

```
pd.read_csv("quotes.csv", parse_dates = {'idx':[1]}, index_col = 'idx')
```

takes about 40 seconds.

Any idea if this can be made quicker? People have suggested Cython solutions [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446744/speed-improvement-on-large-pandas-read-csv-with-datetime-index), but I wonder if a Python/pandas solution exists?

btw, this below does not parse the dates, a bug?

```
pd.read_csv("quotes.csv", parse_dates = [1])
```

Comment: How much slower is it with the `parse_dates`?  I don't think cython is really going to help here (or not be worth the effort anyway, but I could be wrong).  Also you can always read stuff like this as text and then later convert to datetime.

Comment: @JohnE It's 40 sec with parse_dates to read 400k rows. Reading in as string and parsing later takes about the same time -- it is the parsing that's slow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a better option

Taking your 2 lines & making them 400k, reading them in w/o parsing as dates

```
In [34]: %timeit read_csv(StringIO(data + data2*200000),sep='\s+')
1 loops, best of 3: 328 ms per loop

In [35]: df = read_csv(StringIO(data + data2*200000),sep='\s+')
```

Parse the dates, you need to specify a format as this is not an ISO 8601 format, and hence is parsed in python space

```
In [36]: %timeit pd.to_datetime(x.time,format='%Y.%m.%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')
1 loops, best of 3: 2.43 s per loop

In [37]: df.time = pd.to_datetime(df.time,format='%Y.%m.%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')

In [38]: df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 400000 entries, 0 to 399999
Data columns (total 6 columns):
sym      400000 non-null object
time     400000 non-null datetime64[ns]
bid      400000 non-null float64
ask      400000 non-null float64
bsize    400000 non-null int64
asize    400000 non-null int64
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(2), int64(2), object(1)
memory usage: 21.4+ MB
```

Comment: ah thanks. Didn't notice the date part is not ISO format

Comment: Adding the format argument had an enormous effect on the parsing time, as I am using date_time as %d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S.